# How can I get a list of Groups and User names for a given folder in C#

Tags: c#, security, permissions

I found some code that shows how to get a list of users in a given domain. But I'm looking to get the names from just a single folder. My searches aren't getting me very far. Below is an example of the list I'm looking for.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you intend to do with the above list, but what you could essentially do is obtain *Permission Attributes* to the intended directory.  You could essentially *query* like this:

```
// Variables:
string folderPath = "";
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = null;
DirectorySecurity dirSec = null;
int i = 0;

try
{
     // Read our Directory Path.
     do
     {
          Console.Write("Enter directory... ");
          folderPath = Console.ReadLine();
     }
     while (!Directory.Exists(folderPath));

     // Obtain our Access Control List (ACL)
     dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
     dirSec = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();

     // Show the results.
     foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in dirSec.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
     {
          Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Rule {1} {2} access to {3}",
          i++,
          rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow ? "grants" : "denies",
          rule.FileSystemRights,
          rule.IdentityReference.ToString());
      }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.Write("Exception: ");
     Console.WriteLIne(ex.Message);
}

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "...");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

This is a very basic example of *querying* the Directory to obtain the permission levels on it. You'll note that it will show all the physical *accounts associated* as well.  This should *compile* and will essentially show you *Accounts Associated* to the *Directory*.

I'm not sure if this is what you were asking about- Hope this helps.

Comment: @JimDel Not a problem, happy to help.