# Listing all users with access to a folder

Tags: c#, windows, file-permissions

I need to generate a list of usernames with access to a windows folder.

I've used:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\path");
DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Rule:{0}", rule.IdentityReference.));
}
```

Which will give me a list of groups who have access:

```
Rule:NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Rule:BUILTIN\Administrators
Rule:somedomain\Administrators
etc..
```

I've tried this to match users to groups:

```
    using (PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname"))
    {
       using (UserPrincipal UP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(AD, "username"))
       {    
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult<System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal> groups = UP.GetGroups(AD);
        foreach (var g in groups.ToList())
         Console.WriteLine(g.SamAccountName + " + " + g.Sid);
        }
     }
```

Which gives me a list list like:

```
Domain Users
Contractors
Administrators
etc
```

The List of rules from the directory do not match the list of groups from the user. What should I be doing.

I need a function where I can specify a path and it tells me the list of usernames with access. Alternatively I could provide a username to check if they have access. I dont have passwords so I can't impersonate the users.

Comment: Could [this be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603791/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-groups-and-user-names-for-a-given-folder-in-c-sharp/17604113#17604113)? That seems to be able to fetch users (groups as well, though )